# How can I change the Postgres listening port?

Tags: postgresql, vapor

I am using Vapor and in my secretes folder I have `postgresql.json` which contains the following text:

```
{
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "user": "userName",
    "password": "",
    "database": "friends",
    "port": 5432

}
```

The server clearly depends on this file because when I delete this file, it fails to run. However when I include `postgresql.json` and change the port it has no effect on the server. It always listens on port 8080. How can I change my port?

Comment: 8080 is typically the port of your web server, not the Postgres port. To change the port of the Postgres _server_ you need to edit `postgresql.conf`

Comment: Why does the documentation state to enter 5432 as the port in postgresql.json if it has no effect? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I don't know hich documentation you are referring to, but it seems you are confusing the port for the database server with the port of your web server.

Comment: The documentation is here: [document](https://github.com/vapor/postgresql-provider/blob/master/README.md) Also would you be so kind to explain to me the difference between the port for the database server and the port of a web server @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Remember that vapor looks for postgresql.json different places depending on you are running development or production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration file specifies to which database Vapor will try to connect, it does *not* configure the port where the database or the web server listens.

For that, you will have to modify the web server's configuration and restart the web server.